# ggraph can't select columns for geom_node or geom_node_text aes variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, cluster-analysis, aesthetics, ggraph

When I try using variables for geom_node_point or geom_node_text I keep getting errors, no matter what I do. Here's what I was trying at first.

```
library(igraph)
library(ggraph)
library(tidyverse)
graph3 <- graph_from_data_frame(test, directed = F)
ggraph(graph2, layout = "kk") + 
  geom_edge_link(aes(colour = match, alpha = match)) +  geom_node_point(aes(colour = qcluster, alpha =match)) +geom_node_text(repel=TRUE)#  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

but this gives me the following error

> **Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'qcluster' not found**

So then if I try using more precise instructions to show which columns to use, I get other problems

```
ggraph(graph3, layout = "kk") + 
geom_edge_link(aes(colour = match, alpha = match)) +  geom_node_point(aes(colour = test$qcluster, alpha =match)) +geom_node_text(repel=TRUE)#  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

returns the error

> **Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous. Error: Aesthetics must be valid
> data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): alpha = match.  Did you
> mistype the name of a data column or forget to add after_stat()?**

So my questions is, how can I get the columns to work as Aes variables, they seem to work just fine in the `geom_edge_link`, so I'm really confused on what exactly is going wrong. Especially since manually adding aes variables like strings or numbers seems to work just fine.
[The test dataset, it's a very small subsection of my data so testing goes easier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUYZh.png)

| query | subject | qcluster | scluster | match | bit_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16T1_lib200772_4_13 | YP_009910784.1 | cr165 | cr209 | False | 57.4 |
| 16T1_lib200772_4_17 | YP_009910789.1 | cr177 | cr241 | False | 131.0 |
| 16T1_lib200772_4_17 | YP_009910790.1 | cr177 | cr230 | False | 57.4 |
| 16T1_lib200772_4_23 | YP_009910794.1 | cr7 | cr7 | True | 69.3 |
| 16T1_lib200772_4_82 | YP_009910759.1 | cr1 | cr1 | True | 92.8 |
| 16T1_lib200772_4_83 | YP_009910760.1 | cr6 | cr6 | True | 79.3 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also quite new to ggraph - however, what I found out, that when you create a graph with `graph_from_data_frame` (or `as_tbl_graph` when using [tidygraph](https://tidygraph.data-imaginist.com/index.html)) then only one attribute is created for vertices and all other attributes end up as edge attributes which cannot be accessed by `geom_node_...`. So, my workaround is to add vertex attributes manually. The second error message you get is due to the fact that `match()` is a function in R. Here is an example that shows how it could work. In this case I was super lazy and added vertex attributes rather arbitrarily - you need to pick the right attribute for your vertices:

```
test = data.frame(
        query = c("16T1_lib200772_4_13", "16T1_lib200772_4_17",
                "16T1_lib200772_4_17",  "16T1_lib200772_4_23",
                "16T1_lib200772_4_82",  "16T1_lib200772_4_83"),
        subject = c("YP_009910784.1",   "YP_009910789.1",
                "YP_009910790.1",   "YP_009910794.1",
                "YP_009910759.1",   "YP_009910760.1"),
        qcluster = c("cr165",   "cr177",
                "cr177",    "cr7",
                "cr1",  "cr6"),
        scluster = c("cr209",   "cr241",
                "cr230",    "cr7",
                "cr1",  "cr6"),
        my_match = c(FALSE, FALSE,
                FALSE,  TRUE,
                TRUE,   TRUE),
        bitsum = c(57.4,    131.0,
                57.4,   69.3,
                92.8,   79.3))

library(igraph)
library(ggraph)
library(tidyverse)
#library(tidygraph)
graph3 <- graph_from_data_frame(test, directed = F)

#########################################################
#### quick and dirty addition of a vertex attribute: ####
graph3 <- set_vertex_attr(graph3, "qcluster", value = c("cr165",
                "cr177", "cr177", "cr7",
                "cr1",  "cr6", "cr177", "cr177",
                "cr7",  "cr1", "cr6"))
#########################################################

#graph3 <- as_tbl_graph(graph3) 

ggraph(graph3, layout = "kk") + 
  geom_edge_link(aes(colour = my_match)) +
  geom_node_point(aes(colour = qcluster)) +
  geom_node_text(repel=TRUE)#  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Comment: Thanks this really points me in the right direction, but how am I supposed to pick the vertex attributes? Simpy selecting test$qcluster tells me that the number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: One option (assuming that test$query and test$subject don't have duplicates and there is exactly one qcluster that belongs either to test$query or test$qcluster is following (replace code between the comments ##### above):
`my_vertices <- vertex_attr(graph3, "name")
qcluster_vertex_attr <- unname(sapply(my_vertices, function (x) 
 ifelse(x %in% test$query, test$qcluster[test$query == x], test$qcluster[test$subject == x])))
graph3 <- set_vertex_attr(graph3, "qcluster", value = qcluster_vertex_attr)`

Answer (score 1):

To build off of Wolfgang's answer, I've found a way to add vertex information without having to resort to manually applying them. `graph3 <- graph_from_data_frame(test, directed = F, vertices = unique(FileNames))` where FileNames is a file with metadata on my graph. If you combine this with Wolfgang's answer you'll get the graph you were looking for